# Combining 2 BSDF nodes for metallic baking

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, texture-baking, baking

I am trying to bake 2 BSDF nodes into one. They are both metallic, and i was following a video that explains how to bake metallic maps. Normally, i would connect an RGB node that is white to the metallic, preview that RGB node, then bake. As shown here:
[image: (Body Texture has the RGB connected, the RGB is being previewed)]

Now, i wanted to add some masks to my model, that being fingerprints. The fingerprints are alittle metallic to add a bit of reflection, like in real life, how fingers leave some residue behind. I followed Blender Secret's video on how to make custom brushes for masks, which required me to do a different setup here:
[image: (Fingerprint mask and texture there in the middle show what i had made. The texture has its own bsdf, with its own properties.)]

Now the problem i have is trying to combine the two so that they can show up on the same baked image. When i use a mix shader, nothing shows reflective. I tried one after the other, combined the two images into the new material bsdf, and nothing happens. So i am stuck here. How can i bake these two maps? I am sure there is a better way to texture the material, but i did not find anything useful that was close to what i was looking for.

Apologies if this is confusing. Here are the videos that i followed:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrrSBVWFMmk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eE7FedDW2AI&t=0s

Here is the blend file. The material i am working on is called "Body (Prints 1, Body .5)"
Thanks

https://www.mediafire.com/file/ps30m9myvy53qi3/Guitar+J+Baking+REMAKE.blend/file

Answer (score 1):

What I've done is use your provided textures to feed into a single Principled BSDF

This should fix the bake.

In addition, if its a metallic map you are after, you can "fake" it by using the emission slot on the Principled BSDF

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you? THis has been a great breakthrough, but I am still having an issue where the body texture is also supposed to be metallic, or reflective. I am not sure if i am doing something wrong, but i am mixing the body and the fingerprint mask texture together and plugging them into the emission slot, but the bake does not turn out reflective as it would normally. Is there something i am missing? @Sam

Comment: i just noticed that i accidentally put a question mark when i was thanking you, my fault. I am so sorry